# Does the noun "pazzo" come from Pazzi conspiracy?

Tags: etymology, history

This is a question of a language, culture, history, and etymology. I was wondering the relation of the noun **pazzo** has anything to do with the **Pazzi conspiracy**. We know that **Pazzi** name was wiped out from the use in Florence after this plot. However it was strange to connect their surname **Pazzi** and their greed for power.

Back in time, did **pazzo** really mean madman, or it was named after them?

Comment: nice and interesting question bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [De Mauro dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/pazzo), the term “pazzo” is dated 1280.

There is an [example in Boccaccio](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI12/GDLI_12_ocr_895.pdf&parola=pazzo) reported by the “Grande dizionario della lingua italiana”:

> Boccaccio,  VIII-2-27:  Per  questo,  creden­dosi  lui  esser  pazzo,  il  vollero  uccidere.

The etymology of *pazzo* is uncertain, though.

So no, that's just a coincidence. The [family's name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pazzi) apparently comes from a member of it, Pazzo di Ranieri, who distinguished himself in the siege of Jerusalem during the first crusade.

Comment: Just to add a bit of paywalled info, Zingarelli dictionary gives, as etymology and date, “[ lat. _pătiens_, nom., ‘paziente’ (in senso medico) (?) ☼ 1268 ]”; hence, according to this (uncertain, as the ? says) explanation, it would be a cognate of _patient_ (= someone receiving cures).

Comment: Oppure: Pazzo: Probabilmente participio  passato  tronco del lat. volg. *pactiare ‘comprimere, sbattere’, der. del lat. pactum ‘compresso’, nel senso di ‘che ha avuto un colpo, un'ammaccatura alla testa’ •sec. XIII.

Comment: Interesting, @Hachi! Where this piece of information comes from?

Comment: @Hachi Unfortunately Latin *pāctum < pangere* doesn't mean "compressed" but "planted, fixed, settled"; and *pactum < pacīscī* "agreed upon; betrothed", so it's unlikely that **pactiāre* could mean "compress, beat in", and besides there doesn't seem to be any evidence for that verb's existence or meaning. Also, I know of no such thing as a 'participio passato tronco', sounds like this was invented ad-hoc as well.—There does exist *pattume* "rubbish", but the more obvious source of this is *battere.— compingere, compāctum* "to press in or together", with the prefix dropped, is also possible.